# Find: $\sin\left(\frac{2}{\arcsin((x + 4)/5)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, trigonometry

Find: $$\sin\left(\frac{2}{\arcsin(\frac{x+4}{5})}\right)$$

I know:

$$\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$$

I somehow did something that did get this correct.:

$$\sin(2t) = 1 - 2\sin^2(t)$$

So then we see:

the expression equals:

$$1 - 2\sin^2\left( \frac{1}{\arcsin(\frac{x+4}{5})}  \right)$$

I made it:

$$1 - 2\left( \frac{5}{x+4}  \right)^2$$

This worked.

But I dont see how:

$$\sin(\csc^{-1} (x)) \ne \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: You cannot do that. We have that: $$\frac1{\arcsin x} \neq \arcsin\left(\frac1x\right)$$

Comment: @rubik, exactly, but it worked.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the question. Are you claiming $$\sin\left(\frac{2}{\arcsin(\frac{x+4}{5})}\right)=1 - 2\left( \frac{5}{x+4}  \right)^2?$$ Well, it is not. Also, $\sin(2t) = 1 - 2\sin^2(t)$ is wrong, it should be $\cos(2t) = 1 - 2\sin^2(t)$